# problem when pushing rails application on heroku behind proxy

Tags: proxy, heroku, push

I want to push my rails application in heroku cloud. My internet is behind proxy.
I have set my proxy in git bash by following command:

$ export http_proxy=http://host:port

Then I tried to push application by command:

$ git push heroku master

but it gives me error like:

ssh: heroku.com: no address associated with name

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Then I set my proxy by command:

$ git config --global http.proxy http://host:port

But still getting the same error. 
Can you tell me what should I do for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `git` repository is set to use the `ssh` connection type to push or pull to or from heroku. You need to configure your `ssh` client to know how to negotiate your http proxy to reach the outside world. From the `ssh_config(5)` manpage:

```
For example, the following directive would connect via an
HTTP proxy at 192.0.2.0:
            ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -X connect -x 192.0.2.0:8080 %h %p
```

I don't know if your http proxy will let `ssh` through, with or without using the `ProxyCommand` directive, but it could be a good place to start.